U-boot build error on ubuntu missing evp.h file or directory
I am getting an ssl error while compiling u-boot on Ubuntu.
In file included from tools/imagetool.h:24,

                 from tools/aisimage.c:7:

include/image.h:1166:12: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory

 1166 | #  include <openssl/evp.h>

      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:112: tools/aisimage.o] Error 1

make: *** [Makefile:1891: tools] Error 2



expecting a u-boot to compile without any build errors.
Probably missing some libraries.
I am using Ubuntu via virtual box.

Try installing the libssl-dev package to your development host.
